# Java CIpher Columnar Transposition

Tags: java, encryption, transpose

I am not having a good time decrypting the encrypted txt.

```
public class Practica2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a text: ");
        String txt = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a num of columns: ");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        String cipher = cipherTrans(txt, num);
        System.out.println("Coded: " + cipher);
        String decipher = decipherTrans(cipher, num);
        System.out.println("Decoded: " + decipher);
    }

    //This method encrypts
    private static String cipherTrans(String txt, int num) {
        String output = "";
        //takes the length of the string and divides by the num of columns
        int num2 = (int) Math.ceil(txt.length()*1.0/num);
        //2d array 
        char[][] buffer = new char[num2][num];
        int k = 0;
        //loop which will store and rearrange the letter of the txt 
        for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num; j++, k++) {
                if (txt.length() > k) {
                    buffer[i][j] = txt.charAt(k);
                }
            }
        }
    
        //loop which will store the rearrenged txt and output the encrypted txt
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
                output += buffer[i][j];
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    //this method will decrypt the encrypted txt
    private static String decipherTrans(String txt, int num) {
        String output = "";
        int num2 = (int) Math.ceil(txt.length() * 1.0 / num);
        char[][] buffer = new char[num2][num];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num; j++, k++) {
                if (txt.length() > k) {
                    buffer[i][j] = txt.charAt(k);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < num2; j++){
                txt += buffer[j][i];
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

> ```
> Enter a text: 
>
> my name is dani
>
> Enter a num of columns: 
>
> 5
>
> Coded: mm yed  aninasi
>
> Decoded: mdim n  ayaseni
> ```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

> ```
> Enter a text: 
>
> my name is dani
>
> Enter a num of columns: 
>
> 5
>
> Coded: mm yed  aninasi
>
> Decoded: my name is dani
> ```

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to explain with words how this particular cIpher columnar transposition is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The transposition table

This is your ciphertext: `mm yed  aninasi`; key length is `5`.

The transposition table for your particular case looks like this:

```java
char[][] buffer = {
    {'m', 'y', ' ', 'n', 'a'},
    {'m', 'e', ' ', 'i', 's'},
    {' ', 'd', 'a', 'n', 'i'}
};
```

### How to generate the transposition table?

> *"... the recipient has to work out the column lengths by dividing the message [ciphertext] length by the key length. Then they can write the message out in columns again, ..."*
>
> **From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher#Columnar_transposition**

### How to decipher the message?

Once you have generated the transposition table, simply read it row by row, from left to right.

### Solution

The working decipher method, based on your code, could look like this:

```java
private static String decipherTrans(String txt, int num) {
    int num2 = (int) Math.ceil(txt.length() * 1.0 / num);

    char[][] buffer = new char[num2][num];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num2; j++, k++) {
            if (txt.length() > k) {
                buffer[j][i] = txt.charAt(k);
            }
        }
    }

    String output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++){
            output += buffer[i][j];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

You just have to have a clear idea of what you are doing to use the array indices correctly.